# Странная фильтрация данных

Tags: php, фильтры

Всем привет, прошу срочной помощи, есть модуль статических страниц, всё вроде хорошо работало на локалхосте, но, когда перенесли скрипт на хосинг, появилась проблема, она заключается в следующем - когда редактируешь на локалхотсе - всё хорошо, а когда на хостинге - когда указываешь css классы, он начинает ставить кавычки:

```
 <div class=\"row\">
 <div class=\"span4\">
```

Самое странное, что на ПК всё ок, а на сервере работает по другому, вот код обработчика:

```
$sql = $db->prepare("UPDATE pages SET title = ?,url = ?,text = ?, description = ?, keywords = ? WHERE id = ?");
            $sql->bind_param('sssssi',$title,$url,$text,$description,$keywords,$id);
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $title = $_POST['title'];
            $url = $_POST['url'];
            $text = $_POST['text'];
            $description = $_POST['description'];
            $keywords = $_POST['keywords'];

            $sql->execute() or die("Предупреждение о неудачном запросе");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
phpinfo();
```

Там посмотреть опцию `magic_quotes_gpc`. Бесплатные хостинги любят ее включать. Один из способов отрубить -- `ini_set()`

Comment: ini_set() - у меня нигде такой функции нет, я её не вызывал, magic_quotes_gpc было On, сделал Off 
и ничего

Comment: А как вы сделали (хостеру) `off` если не секрет? `ini_set()` для этого как раз нужен..

Comment: что-то тупанул) ini_set( 'magic_quotes_gpc', 0 ); не помогло

Comment: Можно еще в `.htaccess` добавить такие строчки `php_value magic_quotes_gpc Off`